# suddenly i get error #1366 for not having a default value for my columns

Tags: mysql, sql

lets say i have table called `ads (  user_id , title , text , admin_seen )`

admin_seen column is an `int (1)` without any default value  or `DEFAULT(none)`

i used to be able to add a row to this table without filling in `admin_seen` and since it's a `int` column it would get `0` as value automatically

```
insert into ads  (  user_id , title , text ) value ( a , b ,c )
```

suddenly today i keep getting this error in my framework

```
"Field 'admin_seen' doesn't have a default value"
```

and when i try to run the same query from phpmyadmin i get

```
#1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'admin_seen' at row 1
```

i know i can solve this by adding a default valu (0) to admin_Seen column but why is this happening now and how can i change it back  ? i mean i never had to set default value for int columns before and they would get 0 as value automatically

plus they are about hundred tables like this and it would be a lot easier to solve it without having to change every single table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depending on the value of the **[sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html)** system variable.

To determine the current global or session sql_mode value, use the following statements:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
```

If you found the `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` or `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` is on, then for a transactional table, an error occurs for invalid or **missing values** in a data-change statement.

Comment: so you're saying someone has changed sql settings  ? is it ok if i turn `STRICT...`  off ?

Comment: @max This is depends on you.

Comment: well apparently it was off before and it was working fine ... so i guess i will turn it off again   , than